# Multiple Remote Desktop Users connect to one server

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

How can I connect multiple users to a server simultaneously at the same time? I am using Windows Server 2003

Comment: By connect do you mean to open a desktop (RDP) session or connect to shared resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean connection through remote desktop: This depends on the licensing model you chose during the installation phase. If you have not changed the default settings, two users are allowed to connect remotely plus one user working on the console (which may also be remotely). But there are also other licensing models. [This page of the Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/howtobuy/licensing/overview.mspx) may help you if you have questions to the licensing models.

Answer (score 1):

simply connect them at the same time using remote desktop connection.

you can also connect to the console session by using /admin switch

If you want more than 2 people connected at once, look in to Terminal services licensing.

Comment: On Windows < Vista the `/console` switch tells mstsc to connect to the console.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as that. With mstsc.exe v6.1+ /console changed to /admin. v6.1+ is installed by default with XP SP3, Vista SP1 and Server 2008, but could also be installed on earlier versions. See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2007/12/17/changes-to-remote-administration-in-windows-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I was sure it was /console, but after getting rated down in another post for not testing it, I wanted to double check and I did mstsc /? and it said /admin! I wanted to be accurate!